# Agrupar dados SQL PHP com soma dos registros

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
    $this->db->select('tbl_supplier.supplier_name, tbl_order_details.*');
    $this->db->join("tbl_supplier", "tbl_supplier.supplier_id=tbl_order_details.supplier_id");
    $this->db->where('tbl_order_details.order_id', $id);
    $this->db->get('tbl_order_details')->result();
```

O meu retorno no SQL é o seguinte:

```
SELECT `tbl_supplier`.`supplier_name`, `tbl_order_details`.*
FROM (`tbl_order_details`)
JOIN `tbl_supplier` ON `tbl_supplier`.`supplier_id`=`tbl_order_details`.`supplier_id`
WHERE `tbl_order_details`.`order_id` =  '6'
```

E no banco de dados me retorna o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Funciona como deveria, porém, eu preciso que nessa listagem eu consiga agrupar por produto e somar quantidade e sub_total.

*obs: Eu posso ter produtos diferentes nessa listagem, não necessariamente um tipo só.*

Resultado esperado:

Notebook Dell i5 | 15 unidades | Total R$ 20.464,29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você inserir a soma no inicio do seu select agrupando pelo código do produto. Veja:

```
SELECT `tbl_order_details`.`product_name`, 
    sum(`tbl_order_details`.`product_quantity`) as unidades, # soma de quantidades
    sum(`tbl_order_details`.`subtotal`) as total # soma de valores
FROM `tbl_order_details`
JOIN `tbl_supplier` ON `tbl_supplier`.`supplier_id`=`tbl_order_details`.`supplier_id`
WHERE `tbl_order_details`.`order_id` =  '6' 
GROUP BY `tbl_order_details`.`product_code`; # agrupar por código do produto
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f281f/1)**

**No Codeigniter:**

```
    $this->db->select(   // somas
        'tbl_order_details.product_name, 
        sum(tbl_order_details.product_quantity), 
        sum(tbl_order_details.subtotal)'
    );
    $this->db->join("tbl_supplier", "tbl_supplier.supplier_id=tbl_order_details.supplier_id");
    $this->db->where('tbl_order_details.order_id', $id);
    $this->db->group_by('tbl_order_details.product_code'); // agrupamento
    $this->db->get('tbl_order_details')->result();
```